# modelling known regime shifts

Tags: time-series, modeling, market-regimes

I wish to model a price time series with a known regime shift: electricity price before during and after the introduction of a carbon price.  The time series looks like this:

[image]

you can see the jump in price between 2012 and 2014.  [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.55.7429&rep=rep1&type=pdf) states that

"when the sample regimes are known. If the first regime includes the first $i_0$ observations of $P$ total observations, and the structural change is confined to the first $k$ parameters, $\beta_j$, $j = 1 \dots k$, of $K$ total parameters, we can define a dichotomous variable $D$ such that

\begin{equation}
\quad D = \begin{cases} 0 \quad \text{ if } \ i = 1, \dots, i_0 \\ 1 \quad  \text{ if } \ i = i_0 + 1, \dots, P\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Our model is then

\begin{equation}
\quad y_i = \sum_{j=1}^{K} \ x_{ij} \beta_j + \sum_{j=1}^k \ (x_{ij} D_i) \gamma_j + e_i
\end{equation}

where the change in the structural parameter associated with the $x$’s in the second regime is represented by the $\gamma_j.$"

I have tried to run this model in the following form

\begin{equation}
\quad D = \begin{cases} 0 \quad \text{ if } \ i = 1, \dots, i_0, i_1 + 1, \dots, P \\ 1 \quad  \text{ if } \ i = i_0 + 1, \dots, i_1\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\quad y_i = x_i \beta + (x_i D_i) \gamma + e_i
\end{equation}

where the $y$'s are electricity price in AUD/MWh, and the $x$'s are carbon price in AUD/tonne CO2.  This model results in the following residuals

[image]

I have also attempted to run a simple model with the dichotomous variable $D$

\begin{equation}
\quad y_i = D_i \gamma + e_i
\end{equation}

which produces the following residuals

[image]

Neither model seems to completely account for the increase in electricity price due to the carbon price regime.  I am wondering why this is?  Am I using the models correctly?

I am also a bit unclear as to how each model accounts for the regime switch and how they differ.  Any insight is appreciated.